# Basic translator, that translates a vowel into a g

Tags: python

This basic python translator code was supposed to translate every vowel in a letter into G, it does it's job translating vowels into g, but it only translates 2. If I was to write Ga, it translates it into GG, but if I type in Garbo, it only translates it into Gg. What am I doing wrong?

---

```py
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in phrase == "Aeiou" or "aeiou":
            translation = translation + letter  + 'g'
        else:
          translation = translation + letter

    return translation


print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

Comment: Above given code has more problems than stated. It would not give proper output. Please check if you have given the correct code .

Comment: Try to pare this down to a working minimal program which doesn't do what you expect; see the guidance for writing a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error. It's because you failed to check the condition for the second string `"aeiou"`. The second operand of `or` is not a boolean expression but a truthy string. Also the first string must be `"AEIOU"`

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOU " or  letter in "aeiou":
            translation = translation + 'g'
        else:
          translation = translation + letter

    return translation
```

Comment: you don't need to check if in "AEIOU" AND "aeiuo" if you just make the letter lowercase, see my example ^^

Answer (score 2):

easy fix, here you go:

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou": #.lower() to turn letter into lowercase
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation
```

this turns any vowel into a lowercase g, if you want an uppercase G then replace the "g" with "G"

Answer (score 2):

As per your given code snippet, The below code will work to satisfy your requirement.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation
```

But if your requirement is just to translate (replace) vowels with "g", then you can do it using regex substitute rather than looping through each letter.

```
import re
def translate(phrase):
    translation = re.sub(r'[AEIOUaeiou]', "g", phrase)
    return translation
```